# How long does it take for German consulates to process visa appeals?

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals, repeat-visits

My visa was refused from the German consulate in Kolkata and now I appealed to them in writing along with many papers. After submitting all documents they called me suddenly for interview. I was prepared for what they would ask me. I answered all the questions. The interviewer asked when I am planning go to Germany and for how many days. I replied that it was for a birthday party and I would stay a maximum of 15 days. It is my girlfriend who is sponsoring me. This made him skeptical as to why a German girl would sponsor an Indian boy. He was curious about this and asked many times. Lastly, he told me that he would call me. I am very tense about this.

How long is it likely to take for a decision? Will they call me or will they just issue a visa in my name? Can I reapply again?

Comment: I just realized I **assumed** what kind of visa you have applied... you've never actually spelled it out. We need to know what KIND of visa you have applied for.

Comment: No, do not reapply. Your appeal is being worked. Until the appeals process has completed, reapplying would only make things worse.

Comment: So what happened? Did they call you?

Comment: It has been already one month and fifteen days butvsuddenly only the other day I found a mail from Federal Republic of Germany of Kolkata sent meca mail like our decision has been sent to you by courier .The date mention is 7/4/2015 then I enquired the post office since already long time I did not receive my letter.I called the Lady visa assistant to provide mevthe tracking I'd number of the assignment so that I can track the courier.
She is reply told me that its not there to provide me but she asked me to wait next week .I am still waiting .

Comment: what's the update? did you receive the decision letter?

Answer (score 3):

**How long is it likely to take for a decision?**  (German Schengen Appeal)

A Schengen appeal against a consular decision is referred back to Germany and the process can last up to 90 days.  They would have advised you of this in the appeal guidance.

**Will they call me or will they just issue a visa in my name?**

They will usually notify you by email that a decision has been reached and your paperwork will follow in the post.  The email will include the tracking number of the delivery service. Generally, emails do not disclose if the appeal was allowed or dismissed.  If your appeal was allowed, you will asked to schedule a personal appearance at the German consulate to finish the issuing process.

**Can I reapply again?**

If your appeal was dismissed, you will be able to apply again.  Schengen applications have no cooling off period. It is standard advice that you should hold off on a fresh application until you are sure all of their objections have been fixed.

You didn't tell us the reasons for your refusal (or the mitigation in your appeal), but you might find this [question/answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten) useful.  Also [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten).